# Serving a larger video via HTML5, what is the best method for delivery?

Tags: html5-video, cdn

I've developed a site that will eventually go live. It has a decently sized background video. We have it created in HTML5 in the video tag, and we do not prefer to use Vimeo or YouTube for that.

My question is, since this video autoplays (its a background video) and is on the homepage, I'd like for it to load and play fast. I'm just not sure if I should be delivering it via CDN or some video delivery network.

Would it be that big of an advantage to use a CDN for this? Or a video diplay network? What should I consider for displaying this video?

Comment: If it makes any difference, we just used the hosting environment. It's running fine with 10K uniques